# Resolution breakpoints best practice

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

What is the best practice for using breakpoints in CSS? I need to have a mobile breakpoint, tablet (768*1024) and desktop.

Is it with sass variables? CSS custom properties it maybe other way?

Comment: Only three? That does not make too difference. But if you have a complex css, use sass variables or even map like bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You use media queries. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

For example:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: #f00;
  }
  /* css here will take effect when the query is true */
}
```

This will turn the `background-color` of `body` to `#f00` (red) when the width of the screen is 600px or less.

Answer (score 0):

So what I discovered is that there are 2 most common ways to work with resolution breakpoints. The first one is to write the breakpoints in scss variables and then use them as literal (interpolation).

```
$desktop: 'screen and (min-width:1024px)';
```

And then use it like so:

```
@media #{$dektop} {
color:red;}
```

The second way which I prefer is to use mixins with @content

```
@mixin on-dektop {
@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
@content }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
@include on-desktop{
color:red;
}
```

There is an excellent article at css-tricks website
[https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/mixin-manage-breakpoints](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/mixin-manage-breakpoints/)